# DispatchQueue Barrier Not Working As Expected

Tags: swift, asynchronous, synchronous, barrier, dispatch-queue

I have this code in playground

```
import PlaygroundSupport
import Foundation

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "Barrier Test", attributes: .concurrent)

func syncProcess(index: Int) {
    queue.sync {
        print("Sync \(index) Called!")
    }
}

func asyncBarrier(index: Int) {
    queue.async(flags: .barrier) {
        print("Async Barrier \(index) Called!")
    }
}

for i in 0...1000 {
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        asyncBarrier(index: i)
    }
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        syncProcess(index: i)
    }
}
```

And this is the output:

```
Async Barrier 0 Called!
Sync 0 Called!
```

But when I try to reduce the iterations from 1000 to something smaller (i.e. 10), it works correctly

```
Async Barrier 0 Called!
Sync 0 Called!
Async Barrier 1 Called!
Sync 1 Called!
Async Barrier 2 Called!
Sync 2 Called!
Async Barrier 3 Called!
Sync 3 Called!
Async Barrier 4 Called!
Sync 4 Called!
Async Barrier 5 Called!
Sync 5 Called!
Async Barrier 6 Called!
Sync 6 Called!
Async Barrier 7 Called!
Sync 7 Called!
Async Barrier 8 Called!
Sync 8 Called!
Sync 9 Called!
Async Barrier 9 Called!
Async Barrier 10 Called!
Sync 10 Called!
```

I'm just wondering, what happened?

If I changed the asyncBarrier to syncBarrier, it works well even though I used 1000 iterations.

AFAIK, the only difference between asyncBarrier and syncBarrier is whether it'll block its caller thread or not.

Can someone explain this behaviour?

Comment: Race condition, piling up threads?

Answer (score 2):

The key issue is thread explosion on the global queue. If your iterations stay below 64 (the max number of worker threads per QoS), then your code should work fine. But when you exceed that (especially when you have a “wait” in there, which is what `sync` effectively introduces), you are exposing yourself to all sorts of possible deadlock risks.

Usually, when we want to avoid exceeding the number of worker threads, rather than dispatching an arbitrary number of `async` or `sync` calls, we use `concurrentPerform`, which is a parallelized `for` loop, constrained to the number of cores on the device:

```swift
let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "Barrier Test", attributes: .concurrent)

DispatchQueue.global().async {
    DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: 1_000) { index in
        queue.async(flags: .barrier) {
            print("async", index)
        }
        queue.sync {
            print("sync", index) }
        }
    }

    print("all done")
}
```

By using `concurrentPerform`, we will stay well clear of the maximum number of worker threads. This avoids the thread explosion, and the problems that entails.

---

A few caveats:

1. We should also point out that when you are concurrently dispatching to a dispatch queue, there is a race condition, whereby you are not assured the order in which they will reach the dispatch statements. For example, the above example generated the following output:

   ```
   async 0
   sync 0
   async 1
   sync 1
   async 3
   sync 3
   async 2
   sync 2
   async 4
   sync 4
   async 6
   sync 6
   async 5
   sync 5
   ...
   ```

   This is not a problem, per se, as when writing massively parallelized routines, we always write it such that the order of execution doesn't matter. But you should be aware of this and factor this into your design.
2. Make sure that you dispatch enough code to each thread to justify the overhead of the extra thread. In an example like this, the parallel version will actually be slower than the serial version. Now, I assume this was just a one-off experiment, but just remember that “more threads” is not always better. You want to design it to balance the workload per thread.